# Pointing domain to DigitalOcean App Platoform without changing MX records

Tags: domain-name-system, mx-record, cname-record, web-applications, digital-ocean

I am using the newly created App Platform from Digital Ocean. I am trying to point my domain to the server that I created within Digital Ocean. I am told I need to add a CNAME to my domain (since DO only gives me a domain rather than an IP), but from what I understand I can only do this for a subdomain (like www). Is there a way to point my root domain there (to DO) without losing my MX records that point to Google?

Comment: Who told you this?

Comment: MX records doesn't have anything to do with the domain name per se, they can point to other domains than your own. CNAME's are not allowed on root level.

Answer (score 0):

Simply point your domain (example.com WITHOUT the www part) to the IPv4 address of your DigitalOcean app. This should be an A record.

Then you point the [www.example.com](http://www.example.com) to example.com. This should be a CNAME record.

Leave other records unchanged.

Hope this helps someone out there!

Comment: That's what I'm saying: that DigitalOcean gives you a domain only, not an IP